# How to set java.library.path when install oracle 18c on CentOS8.2?

Tags: java, database, oracle, path, centos

I was installing **Oracle 18c rpm** on **CentOS8.2**, after yum install `oracle-database-ee-18c-1.0-1.x86_64.rpm` and begin to configure by using `"/etc/init.d/oracledb_ORCLCDB-18c configure"` command, i got this **java.library.path** error. It seems my java path is not available.
I then  install java `jre-8u251-linux-x64.rpm` and get nothing different.

```
[root@localhost ~]# /etc/init.d/oracledb_ORCLCDB-18c configure
Configuring Oracle Database ORCLCDB.
java.library.path 系统变量无效或缺少此变量。请为 java.library.path 设置正确值并重试操作。
[FATAL] [INS-00001] 未知的不可恢复错误
   原因: 没有其他信息可用。
   操作: 参阅日志或与 Oracle 技术支持服务联系
   概要:
       - [DBT-00006] 无法创建日志记录目录。
       - [DBT-00006] 无法创建日志记录目录。

Database configuration failed.
```

Anybody can help me?

Comment: What does the non-English bits say?

Comment: It says that the environment variables is invalid or missing

Comment: Double check the installation guide. Especially the bit about which platforms are supported

Comment: Did you set environment variables for java home and classpath?.Before running verify environment `echo $JAVA_HOME` and `which java or java -version`

Comment: $JAVA_HOME is ok, java version is 1.81

Comment: English message from Oracle 19c: "The java.library.path system variable is missing or invalid. Please set java.library.path with a correct value and retry the operation."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the very same problem yesterday and found the solution to be a missing library "libnsl". After executing the following command on CentOS it worked.

> yum install libnsl.x86_64

Comment: Thanks!  This resolved the same problem with Oracle 19c on RHEL 8.4 too!